How to use MapApply with Solve
eq = (A/2 == (2 T ArcTan[\[Pi]/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3) - 2 \[Mu]]])/
      Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3) - 2 \[Mu]] && e/2 == \[Pi] T + (A \[Mu])/2);
mueq = Eliminate[eq, T]
mueqFunc [A_, e_, \[Mu]_] := 
  A^2 \[Pi]^4 + 6 A^2 \[Pi]^2 \[Mu] + 
   12 e^2 ArcTan[\[Pi]/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3) - 2 \[Mu]]]^2 - 
   24 A e \[Mu] ArcTan[\[Pi]/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3) - 2 \[Mu]]]^2 + 
   12 A^2 \[Mu]^2 ArcTan[\[Pi]/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3) - 2 \[Mu]]]^2;
muSolutions = 
 Flatten[Table[{A, e, 
    Flatten[NSolve[
       mueqFunc[A, e, \[Mu]] == 0 && \[Mu] < -Pi^2/6, \[Mu], Reals]][[
     1, 2]]}, {A, 1/2, 1, 1/10}, {e, -1, -1/2, 1/10}], 1]

I want to use MapApply (I don't know what else to use) to use the parameters in muSolutions ( of the form {A,e,mu} ) to solve eq[[2]] for the variable T. However, I do not understand the syntax required to use the command so that the variables A,e,mu are appropriately replaced. My idea was  Solve[eq[[2]], T] /. @@@ muSolutions but this is incorrect. What must I do?
Version "14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

You have to let Mathematica know what is the order of your parameters. I would say the simplest way is to Map your Solve over muSolutions, and make appropriate replacements:
Solve[eq[[2]] /. {A -> #[[1]], e -> #[[2]], μ -> #[[3]]}, T] & /@ muSolutions

And if you really want to use MapApply:
Solve[eq[[2]] /. {A -> #1, e -> #2, μ -> #3}, T] & @@@ muSolutions

